# Windows partition tool will only allow me to format partitions as NTFS or exFat. How do I install Kubuntu on the partition I've made for it?

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, kubuntu, exfat

I have just partitioned my hard drive in Windows to dual-boot Kubuntu and Windows 10. I can't format it in FAT or FAT32... The only options are NTFS and exFat.

I want to use Kubuntu and windows at the same time. Can I install Kubuntu on an exFat partition?

Comment: "How do I install kubuntu on exfat?" not possible. you must pick a POSIX compliant file system (like ext4) during the install of kUbuntu.

Comment: Why are you trying to install Ubuntu on FAT, exFAT or NTFS partitions in the first place? I think you have a misconception about the installation procedure of Ubuntu. During the Ubuntu installation you can partition, format and assign drives (or have the installer do it for you). See [How can I install Ubuntu without removing Windows?](/q/1366/175814) and [Installing Ubuntu Alongside a Pre-Installed Windows with UEFI](/q/221835/175814).

Answer (score 6):

Just leave the partition as **Unallocated**

Then boot from the Ubuntu install media, select install alongside Windows,  and it will automatically detect that it should install to the unallocated partition, and take care of formatting it as EXT4.

Comment: I mean KUbuntu. It's another distro. It's kinda difrent.

Comment: @Non-LinuxMan123 - The installer is the same. Did you try what I suggested?

Comment: I'm gonna try right now.. If i don't respond for longer than hour, this means i wrecked my pc.

Comment: @Non-LinuxMan123 - I'm not seeing any picture.

Comment: can't post any pictures. Firefox keeps crashing on kubuntu, so the best i could do is just try to explain. I have tried recreating that in VmWare, no point. So, I can see 4 options: 3 of them are "Use entire disk" and one of them is "Manual". When I click manual nothing happens. What do i click?

Comment: @Non-LinuxMan123 - You aren't going to get an option to install alongside Windows if you don't have Windows on that VM already.

Comment: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-owEOdrEmitQ/U3oyA_fXuoI/AAAAAAAAB9U/_-aGEjFo8k8/s1600/5.PNG mine is just like this one, I just don't have the first option.

Comment: I'm not talking about VM. I don't have options like this on real machine either.

Comment: So, ignore everything I said about VM. I have 50 GB unallocated and I have Windows installed on my REAL machine. But when I boot up to live Kubuntu, and try to install it, I'm not seeing ANY options to install alongside to windows. Do I click manual? If you say yes, be sure of it. I don't wanna wreck my PC.

Comment: First is system UEFI or BIOS? If Windows 10 from vendor then UEFI. And all Windows 10 use fast start up which really is just hibernation. And Linux will not mount hibernated NTFS to prevent damage. So make sure fast start up in Windows is off. http://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation